# How to perform triple equals as negation

Tags: scala, testing, assert, triple-equals

I am learning scala, and want to write my tests with `===`. However, I am curious if there is a way to do something like this:

```
assert(1 !=== 2)
```

I have tried the above, `!==`, and `!(===)`

Is there any way to get the descriptiveness of `===` and use negation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScalaTest doesn't have a `!==` method (it's actually in the source code and is [commented out](https://code.google.com/p/scalatest/source/browse/trunk/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/Assertions.scala#368)). You could implement your own analogue, like:

```
// Somewhere in the codebase
class ExtendedEqualizer(left: Any) {
  def !==(right: Any) = {
    if (left != right) None
    else Some("%s equaled to %s".format(left, right))
  }
}

object TestUtil {
  implicit def convertToExtendedEqualizer(left: Any) = new ExtendedEqualizer(left)
}

// In your test class
import TestUtil.convertToExtendedEqualizer
```

Then it becomes as simple to use as `===`:

```
assert(3 !== 2+2)
```

Note that this is a simplified version of `===` that doesn't do deep array comparisons and doesn't generate a nice diff like ScalaTest does.